# Prevent file from being changed under Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

What's the command under Linux to mark a file as "locked"/to prevent any changes from being made to it?

I'm *not* talking about `chmod`. There's a property that can be set (the name escapes me at the moment) which prevents even processes running as root from changing a file. What is this called and how do I set it?

I have forgotten what this is called and without remembering the name the search function on the site and on Google is failing me.

Comment: Are you searching for chattr? Sometimes, memory fails ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
chattr +i <filename>
```

Comment: immutable   (this intentionally left blank)

Comment: To be able to modify again use `sudo chattr -i <filename>`